# I can't seem to figure out how to center align my table

Tags: html-table, alignment, center

```
<table border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Cell1</td>
<td>Cell1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cell1</td>
<td>Cell1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cell1</td>
<td>Cell1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cell1</td>
<td>Cell1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am not good with coding. I've tried but cannot figure it out. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// CSS:

#container {
    text-align:center; // needed if you expect IE 5
}

.centered {
    margin:0px auto; // this sets left/right margin to auto and
                     // centers the element
}


// HTML:

<div id="container">
    <table class="centered" border="0">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Or if you want to style inline:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <table style="margin:0px auto;" border="0">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't hesitate to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <!-- Your table here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I'm using wordpress. I enter in the code and the table is centered in the admin area. But when I go to the site and refresh the page, the table is still on the left side of the page.

Comment: @JackStevens looks like this would have been a helpful information in your question.

Comment: Thanks also for your help Jeff. Dennis' style inline suggestion worked great. Thank you.